# How to make a directory then write file to that directory using variables

Tags: php

```
mkdir("Business_Pages/".$username);
$fp = fopen("Business_Pages/$username".$username".html", "w");

fwrite($fp, "<html> <head> <link rel='stylesheet' href='index.css'>  </head </html>");

fclose($fp);
```

Im trying to make a directory in Business_Pages that works but im also creating a file in that newly created directory named what ever the name of the html input is. Im basically trying to the the variable $username at the end of the pathname but that doesnt work

Comment: So you want `Business_Pages/<username>/<username>.html` or `Business_Pages/<username>.html`

Comment: i got it thanks but Business_Pages/<username>/<username>.html is exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$fp = fopen("Business_Pages/". $username . '/' . $username . ".html", "w");
```

Comment: thanks how are you telling it to go to the back of the filepath just curious how it works

Comment: Your concating just was wrong. See "php concat strings" in google or php.net

Comment: is there any way where if the $username has a space put a _ instead of a space?

Comment: see str_replace function on php.net (it's those main RTFM docs)

Comment: $str = str_replace(" ", "_", "$username"); i put that in but the fwrite stopped working

Comment: Phil, do you have any expirience in programming?

Comment: nope, im teaching myself we dont have any classes in my high school

Comment: Phil, here at SO we like to help in complex cases, not teaching. So you should find some sites that will teach you or buy some books.

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax errors in your code.

```
$contents = "<html> <head> <link rel='stylesheet' href='index.css'>  </head </html>"

$dir = "Business_Pages/$username";
if (!is_dir($dir))
    mkdir($dir);

$filename = $username . '.html';

file_put_contents($dir . '/' . $filename, $contents);
```